# Why does she say "Я понимаешь" and not "Я понимаю"?

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слова, глаголы

I've heard people say "понимаешь" when they clearly intend to mean "I understand", such as in this line from the Serebro song Не Время:

> Я понимаешь, я это чувствую потом мы всё наверстаем, я предчувствую

Why is it "Я понимаешь" and not "Я понимаю"? Does this have some sort of rhetorical effect?

Also, in everyday conversation: I've heard people respond to my question "Понимаешь?" with: "Понимаешь". This has happened more than once with multiple people.

Comment: The **понимаешь** was Yeltsin's favorite filler 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYz6TkaRjIg

Answer (score 27):

Right punctuation is

> Я, понимаешь, я это чувствую, потом мы всё наверстаем, я предчувствую

The translation is

> I, you know, I'm feeling it, we will catch all then, I forefeel it.

"Понимаешь" in this case isn't a really the verb, but acts as a filler. The full phrase would look like "понимаешь ли ты?" (do you understand?)

Comment: A better translation for "всё наверстаем" would be "[we'll] catch up completely".

Comment: Still doesn't explain why I've heard people respond to my question "Понимаешь?" then they say: "Понимаешь". This has happened more than once with multiple people.

Comment: @Isa Am I right (just for clarity) that you've expected to hear "[Да], понимаю"?

Comment: Yes, I expect to hear "Да, понимаю" but instead the speaker answers "Понимаешь"

Comment: It's ungrammatical and perceived as throwing the question back.

Comment: By the way such kind of answer can mean positive or ironical response.

Answer (score 2):

You should say: "Я, понимаешь, ...", or: "Я понимаю". In the first case, "понимаешь" is related to "ты" - not "я".

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker I do this too when talking to someone. Let’s look at понимать and its present tense conjugations to understand.

Я понимаю

Ты понимаешь

Он, она, оно понимает

Они понимают

Вы понимаете

Мы понимаем

So saying я понимаешь looks like it makes no sense, but it is like saying, I, you know, or “I, as you know.”

:)

Answer (score -3):

Я понимаю = I understand

Ты понимаешь = You understand

Я понимаешь = "wrong",

Я, понимаешь (что-то) = I, you know (something)

Comment: Please read other answers to see that it's actually your answer that is wrong.

Comment: Я понимаешь - wrong /// Я, понимаешь, ... = I, you know, ...